# Open a file with special characters in the name with R function read.dbf

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the read.dbf function in R, but the name of the file contains a special character 'ñ' from spanish.

I changed the name of the file, removing the special character. The thing is that there are a lot of files with similar names and maybe this won't be the best to do.

---

```
read.dbf('Soporte_Plantilla_Vigor_Total_Daños_201806_Inicial_Vigor.dbf')
```

---

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in read.dbf("Soporte_Plantilla_Vigor_Total_Daños_201806_Inicial_Vigor.dbf") : 
>     unable to open DBF file

I want to be able to read this type of file names without changing them.

Comment: You want to read multiple DBF-files? Eventually you can adapt the answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Comment: The issue is more related to the special character in the name, I don't know if there's a way to read this type of names with special characters with read.dbf or if I have to change all the names so the function doesn't present the error

Comment: With `Files <- dir(...)` you do not have to type the special characters.